# Why sed regexp digit character class includes CR character if the last digit is at the end of the line?

Tags: linux, bash, regex, sed, carriage-return

I wanted to extract the Content-Length's size from an URL and output the URL + $size on the same line.

The data I worked with:

```
> curl -I -s http://yahoo.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Redirect
Date: Thu, 10 Mar 2016 13:58:34 GMT
Via: https/1.1 ir18.fp.bf1.yahoo.com (ApacheTrafficServer)
Server: ATS
Location: https://www.yahoo.com/
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Language: en
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Y-Trace: BAEAQAAAAADEVnKTAIhTVAAAAAAAAAAA52rmwEDlxSwAAAAAAAAAAAAFLbI13bX.AAUtsjXdvxvBYm3xAAAAAA--
Content-Length: 304
```

Here is a simplified example. I extracted the Content-Length and just cut off the field I need. Instead of the URL I just echo an "a":

```
> size=$(curl -I -s http://yahoo.com | grep "Content-Length:" | cut -f2 -d" "); echo $size"a"
> a04
```

The `"a"` overwrites the first digit.

Turns out the Content-Length header line is closed with a 0D character and along with the numbers comes this Carriage Return.
I thought that `cut` is not smart enough to leave the 0D off, but just by simply changing the extraction to some regexp tool behaves the same:

```
> size=$(curl -I -s http://yahoo.com | grep "Content-Length:" | sed 's/Content-Length: \([[:digit:]]*\)/\1/'); echo $size"a"
> a04
```

Which means the [[:digit:]] character class *also* included the 0D character. I tried to explicitly mark the end of the string and it worked:

```
> size=$(curl -I -s http://yahoo.com | grep "Content-Length:" | sed 's/Content-Length: \([[:digit:]]*\).*/\1/'); echo $size"a"
> 304a
```

TL;DR: why the regexp character class included the 0D character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't.

```
strintg:     Content-Length: 304\0d
matched:     Content-Length: 304
replaced by:                 304
result:                      304\0d
```

It wasn't matched, and therefore wasn't removed. It just stayed there.

Comment: epic mindlock happened.